# Error with my Finding max value program Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

I'm writing a program that finds the maximum value of n numbers inputted. But I realized that inputting only negative numbers doesn't work because i set my initial max value as 0.

```
max_value = 0
response = 0
while response != 'done':
    response = input("Please enter a number. If ready to calculate, type 'done'\n")
    if response != 'done':
        store_prev_1 = max_value
        if int(response) >= store_prev_1 :
            max_value = int(response)
 print(max_value)
```

So basically, can someone help me fix this so that it works for any type of integer/float.

Also, what logic could I follow to do the same for min value? It has to be sort of what I wrote for the max value (after its correction by you fellow smart people)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `float('-inf')` (negative infinity) as the starter value:

```
max_value = float('-inf')
```

*Any* other numeric value is always going to be larger than that value. For searching for a minimum, you can use the positive equivalent, `float('inf')`:

```
min_value = float('inf')
response = input("Please enter a number. If ready to calculate, type 'done'\n")
while response != 'done':
    if int(response) < min_value:
        min_value = int(response)
    response = input("Please enter a number. If ready to calculate, type 'done'\n")

print(min_value)
```